# C# Convert a DataTable to List<string>

Tags: linq, datatable

I have a 1 row DataTable that I'd like to convert to the following format:

Column1Name : value

Column2Name : value

Column3Name : value

etc...

How can this be accomplished with LINQ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
DataTable table = ...

// Overlays the columns over the only row's items
// and combines each column-item pair as required.
var items = table.Columns
                 .Cast<DataColumn>()
                 .Zip(table.AsEnumerable().Single().ItemArray, 
                      (column, value) => column.ColumnName + " : " + value);

var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);
```

Here's another (IMO better) approach:

```
// Uses the DataRow's column-indexer to match a column with 
// the corresponding row-item.
var items = from DataColumn column in table.Columns
            select column.ColumnName  + " : " + table.Rows[0][column];

var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tweaked it so it can work for any number of rows.        'var xxx = from DataRow row in table.Rows
                      from DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns
                      select column.ColumnName + " : " + row[column];'